# Footer area suggestions?

Tags: discussion, design

Not sure where to put this, but I was looking at the footer of for instance StackOverflow.
The bottom portion font is very hard to read, the colors should be looked at:

[image]

This:

`site design / logo © 2013 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required`

for simplicity should be white just like the links.

Also the footer is inconsistent, all other categories have one column except `Technology` it causes a gap between the various categories and just looks odd:

[image]

All categories should indicate a max # of sites ( say 5-7) and then include a link to `more(n)`.

Comment: Funny you single out "Technology" as inconsistent. Why not "Science", or "Other"?

Comment: Because science and other do not span multiple columns.  Did you read my post?

Comment: And yet, on StackExchange.com, only Technology has that many non-beta sites listed. The list of sites is that - non-beta sites in the category.

Comment: But there are more technology related sites that are high profile enough to warrant being in the footer.  I wouldn't want to have to add several clicks just to satisfy your OCD of having one column per category.  It looks just fine.

Comment: Precisely I am not sure where you are going with this.  I am pointing things that jump out at me from a UX perspective.

Comment: @Servy - It looks just fine to you, but if you are looking for consistency this doesn't fit.

Comment: Also @Servy - High profile would be 3 technology sites: superuser, serverfault, and stackoverflow.

Comment: Meh. Just repeat the Technology header thrice. Problem solved.

Comment: @Mat - That would be inconsistent :).

Comment: So, how would you show the 21 graduated technology sites, considering that next highest number of graduated sites in a category is 4 (science)?

Comment: I wouldn't show all 21, I would show a max. # of sites for each category.  If you want to see more you click more.

Comment: @Oded what happens to your footer when you graduate 21 more technology sites?

Comment: @JonH I didn't say "the highest profile" I said "high profile enough to warrant being in the footer".  Why do you feel that the consistency that you describe is worth hampering functionality?  I'm not saying it's not consistent, I'm saying that your solution causes way more significant problems than it solves.

Comment: That would totally break my workflow. I use the footer all the time to switch between my favorites.

Comment: @JonH - Dunno. Cross that bridge when we reach it.

Comment: Mat - Right the functionality already exists, you just said it.  You want to switch to your favorites?  So use your favorites or bookmarks bar in your favorite browser.

Comment: There already are more than 21 sites under Technology. The last link is **more (14)**.

Comment: @Servy - what problems arise with my proposed solution.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - 14 _beta_ sites. The 21 are _graduated_ sites.

Comment: @JonH Not having links that I want in the footer when I go to find a technology related site and needing one or more additional clicks to get there.

Comment: @Oded, oh, I see, thanks. Never thought there was a distinction there :)

Comment: @Servy - I too would like google reader to continue working but its long gone - get my point?

Comment: When there are 21 more technology sites you make the footer deeper/longer, or maybe there's 21 more science sites and it needs two columns now... either way it's at the bottom of the page, space is cheap.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - it is cheap, but at the cost of losing consistency.  Notice how the stackexchange sites are horizontally centered so that it flows - there's a reason to that - it's known as design.  If you begin to fill up the footer with even more links then the footer becomes too wide with content that does not flow.  Point being there is too much irrelevant information there.  And for the few that want it there is a favorites / bookmark bar.

Comment: @JonH: agreed on the color/contrast of the licence line though. (But won't get my vote while it's lumped with the other suggestion).

Comment: @Mat - Good we agree on one point - I'm halfway there ;).  Can we fix those colors, it is very hard on the eyes.

Comment: @JonH The argument that there are too many links in the footer, thus making it harder to find the relevant links, is *entirely* different than saying that "the technology section is inconsistent, it should be fixed regardless of it's effect on functionality."  If you wanted to assert that certain links should be removed simply because they aren't clicked enough to be considered useful then that's a change designed to improve functionality, not to improve some meaningless metric of "consistency" at the *expense* of functionality.

Comment: I agree on the font color but disagree on the columns. To upvote or not to upvote; to downvote or not to downvote - that's the question.

Comment: @CamilStaps - You can be neutral.  The nice thing about this is it brings up good discussion and the font color is just hard on the eyes so if we fix one thing it was worth mentioning.

Comment: [Repeating the column title _does_ make it look nice](http://i.stack.imgur.com/krLab.png).

Comment: @Mat - I'm glad you notice that now.

Comment: What? You dismissed that suggestion a few minutes ago :-(

Comment: Compare what @Mat posted to this http://i.imgur.com/fmckbvX.png

Comment: It means the more is in the wrong place @Mat :-). Try it again with 3 technologies...

Comment: @Mat - well I'd rather it repeat the name then the gap.  I'd rather it get rid of multiple columns for one category but obviously that doesn't look to be happening.

Comment: @jin lookie here, you're the man that works on the design.

Comment: I can read this fine with my eyes.

Comment: Well thats because you're the Fresh Prince :).  The colors of `cc-wiki` and `attribution required` is probably what is killing it, but I'd prefer it was #fff.

Comment: `me-a user who has used the stack sites probably more than you` - why do you think you have used the sites more than @Servy? And even if you did, why does that qualify you to have better judgment about how the footer should look / function? Why do you care more about how it looks than how it functions? If you used the footer and your favorite site was now an extra click away, is that "better"? Why should I be forced to use bookmarks instead? What if I already have plenty, or if I have 30 favorite stack sites that are currently all shown in the footer? It's just clutter elsewhere.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - NO specific reason my point being is I know the sites to navigate them.  A new person to the site doesn't, that is all.  Don't think I was looking for any entitlement so calm down buddy.  As for bookmarks bar/favorite versus all the sites on the footer, that is **your** personal preference.  From a UX point it isn't consistent.  The folks coming on here trying to stir some sort of controversy please stop with the drama, discussion and change is good.  It's what makes companies successful, that is why we have admins on the site.  So please I am just looking for discussion.

Comment: I am perfectly calm. I just disagree with your assessment / preference that "consistent" means "100% symmetrical."

Comment: @AaronBertrand - And that is great, this is what is great about discussion some points are agreed upon and others not.

Comment: I don't understand - you are getting discussion. This is the definition of proposing an idea and interacting with people who don't agree with you. If all you can say is "stop with the drama" and "calm down buddy" then I propose that you're mixed up about who is and who is not willing to have a discussion.

Comment: Right @AaronBertrand - but don't add stuff like this:  `why do you think you have used the sites more than @Servy? And even if you did, why does that qualify you to have better judgment about how the footer should look / function?` that is drama.

Comment: Wow, *you* brought up that you used the sites more than @Servy. *shrug*

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Right, look at the context, the point of the discussion was for consistency and for new users. I have been around to understand the categories, the sites, etc.  But imagine a new user, that was my point.

Comment: @JonH You imagine a new user will what?  Not realize that "Sharepoint" is actually in the "technology" category?  Not know what category "IT Security" falls in?  Think that the site is ugly and never come back again?  What particular problems are you asserting are likely to result from the current behavior?

Comment: I think they might just get dizzy because the footer isn't perfectly balanced.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh no, I need to look at the SE footer; better take some Dramamine.

Comment: @Servy - And what would be the impact if you clicked a "more" link to see the additional IT related sites?

Comment: @Servy - Please stay on topic.

Comment: @JonH people don't like extra, unnecessary clicks. Form over function makes sense in some contexts, but not all.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - That is fine but again that is your personal preference.  To me the logical step is that each category has one column with a max # of sites and a link to additional sites.  Ever hear of the KISS principle?  Discussions are good see :).

Comment: Because you've asked for two feature requests here and people are obviously divided about them, I strongly recommend splitting them up. This question can never be adequately resolved as it stands.

Comment: KISS can also mean "don't make me click through to another page"...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - That's fine I wasn't looking for a defentive answer, that is why I picked the `discussion` tag...hence the discussion.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Right but that is based on your preference.  It's the same reason Jeff Atwood did not want to implement a "Watch this question" feature, and I'm not talking about question favorites.  We have a browser bookmark bar for that...this falls into the same idea.

Comment: @JonH by that argument, I could start up a discussion that asks "what does everyone think of purple?" and on the next line "What's your favorite Beatles' song?" Why should a splintered discussion have to treat two separate aspects of the site?

Comment: I've only ever looked at the footer because this meta question was posted. Before that, you couldn't have convinced me that it actually existed.

Comment: Sorry, but this is growing rather boring. I'm going to go take my Dramamine now in case I look at the footer for too long. Does anyone know a quick cure for vertigo?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - The discussion may end up divided but it might initiate some sort of internal discussion, testing, or change to see what fits.  Just because you have discussion doesn't mean you have results instantaneously.

Comment: @AaronBertrand- That was off topic, but thanks.

Comment: Going to have to agree with @swasheck on this one I had no clue the footer even existed. This may be the most irrelevant topic on all of Meta and that is saying something.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I hear Alfred Hitchcock had a great one.

Comment: @JonH the irony is that you seem to think you do

Comment: @JonH why can you speak for 20 million users, and decide for them that if they want to click through to database administrators it is better for them to create a bookmark or click twice just to make sure the same number of sites are represented in every category?

Comment: @swasheck - Because I brought up a discussion?  Boy what would we have done had meta never existed?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I thought you were bored, apparently not so much.  That is exactly my point of discussion - never once did I mention this should be the way.  I am pointing out things just as others on `meta` have pointed out in the past.  That is the point of the tag `discussion`.  If we discuss it and it is not agreed by the core folks and the developers at stackexchange I am fine by that.

Comment: I'm still waiting on an answer to [my previous comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180225/footer-area-suggestions?noredirect=1#comment546473_180225).  What problems are you asserting exist as a result of the way the site currently is.  Keep in mind you're the one proposing a change; I'm not here to justify why the site is the way it is; the burden is on you to demonstrate that there is a problem if you would like it to be addressed.

Comment: @Mat - you are hardly putting what I said into context.  The guy mentioned he's never noticed a footer, I merely said that is not the same as every other user on the site.

Comment: @Servy - My observation is not considered a bug if that is what you think I am trying to file a bug or discussion.  What I am posting is a UX change.  You might want to visit the UX stack exchange site.

Comment: @JonH And are you proposing a change because change is good, or because there is a problem you'd like to fix?  If there is no problem then there is no reason to change anything.  If there is a problem I'd like to know what problem we're trying to solve before we make a change.  Perhaps there's a better way to solve that problem.  We also need some metric to determine how successful our change is.  If we don't know what we're fixing, we can't evaluate if the change is successful.  If there is no problem, then we're spending dev time improving nothing.  Opportunity cost.

Comment: @Servy - No bug problem, stop measuring it as one.  This is a UX change.

Comment: @JonH It's a feature request.  Feature requests need to be justified.  They aren't implemented just because someone proposed them.  They are implemented because they are solving a problem or adding some significant amount of value.  What are you trying to improve?  How will the site be better as a result of the time and effort spent on this request beyond the fact that you think it will be prettier?  There are a *lot* of feature requests submitted; yours would need to add more value for it's cost than any of the others to justify implementing it; as I said, opportunity cost.

Comment: @JonH usually for a "discussion" to gain traction on Meta it has to have some sort of clear benefit. I would say be looking at the overall reacion to this thread that it does not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For me:

- Yes, change the font color. It's kinda weird like this; nowhere else in the footer this color is used.
- No, don't change the columns. There are more technology sites, so I guess there's more interest for technology. So it should get a larger place in the footer, nothing wrong with that. How else do you want to show 21 technology sites and 4 science sites? Hiding a lot good technology sites under a 'more' is not a good idea IMO.

  What *would* be a good idea though, in my opinion, is TronicZomB's idea of using vertical lines between the different columns:

  [image]

  It is suggested here: [SE Footer Changes/Update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180439/205264)

Comment: For point 2 look at it just by reading up and down the columns - turn off your programmer mind for a minute.  Look at it from a new person.  The gap is odd.  For additional sites what are the issues with using your bookmarks bar?  If this was the case why didn't Jeff Atwood support both "Favorite" questions and "Watch"  questions.  His argument was there is a favorites / bookmarks bar to handle that.

Comment: @JonH I sincerely don't have a problem with the gap. Perhaps we could move technology to the left to make it look less odd to you, but I wouldn't like that: technology is the major part of the network, it shouldn't be listed last.

Comment: Fair enough, this is personal preference.

Comment: @JonH You can create a userscript if it bothers you that much.

Comment: "Hiding a lot good technology sites under a 'more' is not a good idea IMO." there is more than one way of 'hiding' a link: putting a link in a list of 20 other links is an excellent way of hiding them all. I'd rather have 5 visible than none!

Comment: @JackDouglas I disagree. Of the sites you use a lot, you know where they are in the footer, so you don't have to search.

Answer (score 5):

Font color: YES!

Categories: I don't like the idea of making them all one column, but I can see where the confusion could possibly arise. What about a small dividing line of sorts between the last column of Technology, the only columns of Life/Arts, Cultrue/Recreation, Science, and Other (4 lines in total)? There is the division that JonH seems should be there as well as we keep all 21 Technology sites in the footer.