# SE Footer Changes/Update

Tags: feature-request, footer

Based upon the discussion from this question, [Footer area suggestions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180225/footer-area-suggestions/180228#180228), I would like to propose an update (feature request?).

I would have to agree that the footer could be confusing for beginner StackExchangers (StackExchangians?). I do not like the idea of shortening the technology section as proposed in the aforementioned post, but I do agree with the changed color on the license links.

I propose the following as an update to the footer, we change the color of the "cc-wiki" and "attribution required" to the same color as the "contact us" and "feedback" links as well underline when hovered over like the other links in the footer (thanks to @hammar for the catch). Also, provide column dividing lines between the sections that will be the same color as the section headers.

[image]

Comment: I don't particularly care about the link colour (although consistency is good), but those vertical lines are a great idea.

Comment: For consistency, those links should probably also have underline on hover like the rest of the links in the footer.

Comment: @hammar Good Catch! I'll edit that in as well.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of footer changes, one of the things that always confuses me is why the "more(xx)" always appears at differing heights.

So I would propose filling the entire column to put the "more(xx)" at the bottom as one would expect.

Comment: I believe that the reasoning for the variations is because only graduated SE sites are shown in the footer. The more is for all SE sites that are still in beta. It wouldn't really make sense to move beta sites to the footer to even out the placement of the "more(##)" since then that would just cause more confusion with a mix of grad sites and beta sites.